# Average numbers searched to find duplicate number

Tags: probability

We have a list of numbers from 1 to n in a random order, except one number appears twice. On average how many numbers do you need to inspect until you know what the duplicate number is?

I know that the answer is that on average you need to inspect 2/3 of the numbers, but I'm having trouble proving it.

If the length of the list, $l = n + 1$ (since there's one duplicate), then to have a 50% chance of finding the duplicate number we need to solve:
$$
0.5 = \frac{(l-2)}{l} * \frac{(l-3)}{l-1} * \frac{(l-4)}{l-2} * ...
$$

Answer (score 1):

This is asking for the mean position of the maximum $M$ of a pair of integers chosen uniformly at random in $\{1,2,\ldots,n+1\}$. For every $k$, the event $[M\leqslant k]$ happens when one chooses a first integer $\leqslant k$ then a second integer $\leqslant k$ and different from the first one, hence
$$
P[M\leqslant k]=\frac{k}{n+1}\cdot\frac{k-1}{n}.
$$
Thus,
$$
E[M]=\sum_{k=0}^{n}P[M\gt k]=n+1-\sum_{k=0}^{n}P[M\leqslant k]=n+1-\frac1{n(n+1)}\sum_{k=0}^{n}k(k-1).
$$
Since the very last sum is $\dfrac13n(n-1)(n+1)$, one gets
$$
E[M]=\frac23(n+2).
$$